# Can I emulate the screen of a tab 7 on a tab 10

Tags: android

The question I am asking if there is a way to crop part of the screen on a tablet 10 to make it behaves like a tablet 7 I tried searching but found nothing.

I am asking because I'd like to  test on a real screen for tab 7 and I only have a tab 10 at this moment .

I tried setting the layout width and height to the tab 7 dims but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use the emulator in eclipse or android studio ?

Comment: I do but from perverse experience the emulator doesn't always behave like an actual device

Comment: I agree. But sometimes thats the only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the activity manager via adb.

To emulate the original Nexus 7 model, use

```
adb shell am display-size 1280x800
```

or for the second edition use

```
adb shell am display-size 1920×1200
```

Answer (score 0):

Create emulator based on your need/requirement

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible without any modifications to the OS.

If you are looking for a more realistic alternative to the emulator, I'd recommend having a look at the Remote Test Lab at developer.samsung.com. They offer a way to run you app on real devices (Galaxy Tab 3 (7.0), Note 3, Note 2, S2, S3, S4) that are mirrored via the Internet. You can fully control them.

It's completely free.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion that might help.